# JUnit4 -> JUnit5, service unit test code does not work

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

Spring Boot Version : 2.1.6
JUnit Dependencies Version : 5.3.2 (Higher versions are not available (Not working))

build.gradle

```
dependency {
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit-vintage:junit-vintage-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner)
}
```

Other common JUnit5 test codes work well.
Bit Service Layer Unit test is not Working.

JUnit4 Test Code : Works very well

```
import org.junit.Test;
// ....

public class SomeServiceUnitTest {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @InjectMock
    SomeServiceImpl someService;

    @Mock
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Test
    public void somethingTestForSuccess() {
        // GIVEN
        when(someRepository.getSomething("abc")).thenReturn(100);

        // WHEN 
        boolean result = someService.doSomething("testObject");

        // THEN 
        assertTure(result);
    }

}
```

But, JUnit5 : Mock Repository is `NullPointException`

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
// ....

class SomeServiceUnitTest {

    @Rule
    MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @InjectMock
    SomeServiceImpl someService;

    @Mock
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Test
    void somethingTestForSuccess() {
        // GIVEN
        when(someRepository.getSomething("abc")).thenReturn(100);

        // WHEN 
        boolean result = someService.doSomething("testObject");

        // THEN 
        assertTure(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: „Rule“ is a JUnit 4 mechanism. You’ll have to replace it with  a Jupiter extension.

Comment: Use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on your test instead of the `MockitoRule`.

Answer (score 0):

In your JUnit 4 code snippet the @Mock annotated fields are initialized because you are loading Mockito with the MockitoRule. Mockito takes care of the creation of your mocks and assigns them to the @Mock annotated fields.

But JUnit 5 does not support rules:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support

In your JUnit 5 test class the @Rule annotated MockitoRule field is ignored, therefore Mockito is not loaded and the @Mock annotated fields are not assigned.

To load Mockito in your JUnit 5 test class remove the MockitoRule and instead annotate the class with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class).